# can I add more widget inside the image on flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface

Just started to learn fultter and I am trying to create a login page on flutter for an app and I found an image as the background of the login page. Is it possible to add some text and input field on the image ? Please let me know if there's a way to do so. Thanks.

Comment: yes you can pub a widget over another widget using the Stack widget

Comment: There's  a lot of examples out the check this one https://github.com/tonydavidx/LoginPage_with_background/tree/Starter-Project

Answer (score 0):

Yes, You have to use [Stack](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=liEGSeD3Zt8&t=1s) widget for that. Initial one has your image and for textField you can add widget with Position.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Container(
  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.cover,
      image: AssetImage('asset_image'),
    ),
  ),
  child: Column(
    children: [
      // Form field
    ],
  ),
);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?